# NotificationBuilder.addAction().autoCancel() not work in Android 6.0

Tags: android

I have an notification in my app and this notification has button that was set using addAction()method. But every time that user click in the button of the notification the notification don't auto cancel unless that user clicked explicitly in the notification.

```
private static void notification(Context context, String title, String text, int id, Intent intent, int priority, boolean withSound) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(text);
    notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bg_primary));
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(priority);
    if (Constants.NOTIFICATION_NEW_AD_BALANCE == id)
        notificationBuilder.setTicker(text);
    if (Constants.NOTIFICATION_DATE_TIME_SETTINGS == id)
        notificationBuilder.addAction(0, context.getString(R.string.notification_device_time_settings), pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));

    if (withSound) {
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500});
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I have to start my notification using the following pending intent:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

After I have to implement a broadcastreceiver to be triggered when user perform the click on notification button how can you see below:

```
public class DateTimeSettingsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        NotificationBuilder.cancel(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_DATE_TIME_SETTINGS);
    }
}
```

This way the problem of notification not being dismissed after user perform click was solved.

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect from `setAutoCancel()`? Reading the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)), it says

> Setting this flag will make it so the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it in the panel.

It sounds like your code is working correctly. I believe you want the previous notification to dismiss when a new one is added? I can't remember for sure, but I think if you use the same `id`, it will replace the current one. Otherwise, I know you can cancel the notification with it's `id`:

```
notificationManager.cancel(id);
```

Comment: I need that notification be closed when the user click in the notification button and this is not workin even using:
    notificationBuilder.addAction(0, context.getString(R.string.notification_device_time_settings), pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: Well, `setAutoCancel()` does not do that. You need to manually dismiss the current notification.

Comment: How can I intercept the button click to dismiss the notification manually.

Comment: @JackMiras check my answer